# Spreadsheet formula to look up array of comma-separated SKUs and return product names associated with SKUs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I've got a hard spreadsheeting problem that would really be terrific to solve.

I'm trying to track sales on a spreadsheet (see 1st screenshot). Each sale has a unique order number and each product has a unique SKU. I also have a separate sheet with two columns: SKU and product name (see 2nd screenshot).

I'd like to enter a comma separated list of SKUs in column B and show a concatenated list of the product names pulled from the separate sheet in column D (ideally with line breaks).

What formula is needed to produce column D?

Edit: Although my screenshots depict Google Sheets, an answer for Excel is perfectly fine as well.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Share sample sheet.

Comment: I would love to. I'm not seeing how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

It would be good to test it out on more data, but try:

```
=arrayformula({"Items ordered";trim(flatten(regexreplace(query(transpose(if(B2:B<>"",iferror(vlookup(split(B2:B,","),{Sheet2!A:B},2,0),)&char(9999),)),,9^9),char(9999)&"\ ?",char(10))))})
```

[image]

Comment: I am attempting to get this to work for me now. That's quite a formula. Thanks for your assistance!